# Scrapy - Trouble getting output from xpath/css

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is a sample link i am scraping:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-ZLINE-30-in-Wooden-Wall-Mount-Range-Hood-in-Walnut-Includes-Remote-Motor-KBRR-RS-30/311456581?MERCH=REC-_-rv_gm_pip_rr-_-303727628-_-311456581-_-N

[image]

I'm trying to get the internet number and I have tried both css and xpaths

**Here's what I've tried**

```
productOMS = product.xpath("//span[@id='product_ID']").getall()
```

or

```
productOMS = product.css(".product_internet_number::text").getall()
```

and here is the html snippet I'm trying to scrape:

```
<span itemprop="productID" id="product_internet_number" class="" style="" xpath="1">311456581</span>
```

I also used a xpath selector extension on chrome which gave me

[image]

when I use CSS I have a blank field returned and when I use xpath I get something like:

"< span itemprop="productID" id="product_internet_number">312028174"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
response.xpath("//span[@id='product_internet_number']/text()").extract()
```

if you are following up in a sub-selector named `product` from response object then:

```
product.xpath(".//span[@id='product_internet_number']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: that solved it! ill mark as an answer when it lets me